# <input type="file"> is not working with document.value();

Tags: php, html, input, upload

Im trying to let the user upload the image, and when the image is done uploading, you can click the add image button and it will add to the textbox as an img src. Though, it is returning with [object HTMLInputElement] as similar to null, why is this happening?

```
function added() {
   var image = document.getElementById('fileToUpload');
   document.getElementById('media_post').value = '<img src="http://lit.life/gallry/<?php echo $dir_auth1; ?>/uploads/">' + image;
 }

 <form action="upload1.php" method="post" id="addedImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

```
 <textarea rows="4" cols="45" id="media_post" name="media_post" form="usr_post" maxlength="300" method="get">

</textarea>
```

Comment: The code you have provided in your example dose not seem to make much sense. Shouldnt the JS be in script tags?

Comment: @DanWalker yup. It is. Though, it actually is in my script, just not on StackOverFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to display the `<input>` element, not its value.

```
   var image = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').value;
```

If you want this filename to become part of the image URL, you need to put it inside the `src` attribute.

```
document.getElementById('media_post').value = '<img src="http://lit.life/gallry/<?php echo $dir_auth1; ?>/uploads/' + image + '">' ;
```

```js
function added() {
  var image = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').value;
  document.getElementById('media_post').value = '<img src="http://lit.life/gallry/aidan/uploads/' + image + '">' ;
}
```

```html
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="added()">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">

<br>Preview
<br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="45" id="media_post" name="media_post" form="usr_post" maxlength="300" method="get">

</textarea>
```

Comment: Ok, then what can I change it to besides `.value` that would be really nice for that info.

Comment: `.value` will be the filename from the `input`. What do you want it to show next to the image?

Comment: Yes that is what Im trying to do. Put that file name input inside an `img src` into the textbox.

`<img src="http://lit.life/gallry/aidan/uploads/">[object HTMLInputElement]` 

does that help?

Comment: It's not inside the `<img>` element, it's just text next to the image.

Comment: If you make the fix I showed, itg will become `<img src="http://lit.life/gallry/aidan/uploads/">filename`

Comment: Ok, so how would I take the file's name from the upload and put it in the `document.getElementById()` into the `.value` thanks

Comment: If you want it to be part of the image URL, you should put it before `">`

Comment: Ok, that is what im looking for, but I want the "filename" to be inside of the img src tag.

Comment: If you want to get a preview of the image itself you should look into using the HTML5 File API. Here is a good resource link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-html5-file-api-to-work-with-files-locally-in-the-browser

Comment: But a `textarea` doesn't render its contents, it just displays it for editing. Maybe you should put this into the `innerHTML` of a `DIV`. Or just have an image element, and do `document.getElementById('media_image').src = ...`

Comment: @Barmar thanks, but it is still returning with [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: Even though you fixed the assignment to `var image` as I showed in my answer?

Comment: It is now giving me a C:\fakepath\image.png.
Why is the fake path appearing?
Any idea as to why?

Comment: It also shows how to remove that, and just get the filename part.